# Vue2 $emit not firing the callback

Tags: vuejs2

Using Vue2, I have a list of books on a page where the details are shown via a child component. The user can delete one of the books from within the child component. I want the list to update after the delete. I'm using an $emit from the child after the record is deleted from the database. I can see from the console that the $emit is sent with the correct new list of books in the payload. However, the callback function in the parent isn't being fired. I can tell because the console.log I have at the beginning of the callback isn't showing up in the console.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's what's in the parent:

```
<div v-for="book in books" :key="book.BookID"  @book-refresh="refreshbooks">
  <BookCard :book="book" />
</div>
```

Here's the callback function:

```
async refreshbooks(newbooks) {
  console.log('in books.vue, starting refreshBooks, newbooks is: ', newbooks)
  this.$set(this, "books", newbooks)
  .bind(this)
},
```

Here's what's in the function (in the child component) that fires the $emit:

```
async deleteBook(bookID) {
this.dialogdelete = false
await (EventService.deleteBook(bookID, this.user.UserID))
  .then((newbooks) => {
    this.$emit('book-refresh', newbooks)
  }
    )

},
```

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] like a codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

TJ, thank you for the suggestion. I did as you said and created the mre which worked. I then went back to see what was different. The only things I changed were the name(s) of the functions. I changed the book-refresh and refreshbooks all to a simple refresh. Now it works perfectly. I haven't taken the time to see if I just didn't have the names matched up properly or if there's just something about hyphenated names? I did read somewhere yesterday that mixed case makes a difference, so maybe? In any case, keeping it super simple has helped me to move on.

Thanks again for helping me see the forest instead of the trees!